# Default override handler

Tags: java, overriding

Is there a way to define a default, or fallback, overriding method that can handle any unhandled methods?

The reason I ask this is because I've made a class to override a class in a function library that is constantly subject to change. In order to successfully compile the class, all methods must be defined and overridden, but I don't really want to be recoding my class every time there is an update.

Here's an example of what's written:

```
public class CommandSignsPlayerProxy implements Player {

    private Player proxy;
    private boolean silent;

    public CommandSignsPlayerProxy(Player targetPlayer) {
        this.proxy = targetPlayer;
    }

    public boolean isSilent() {
        return silent;
    }

    public void setSilent(boolean silent) {
        this.silent = silent;
    }

    @Override
    public void abandonConversation(Conversation conversation, ConversationAbandonedEvent details) {
        proxy.abandonConversation(conversation, details);
    }

    // This function is basically the only one that NEEDS overriding
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (!silent)
            proxy.sendMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFlySpeed(float arg0) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        proxy.setFlySpeed(arg0);
    }

}
```

In the real code, there is another 50+ overridden functions. So is there a way to make an automatic handler that overrides `function_name()` with `proxy.function_name()`?

Comment: When I implement interfaces that have many methods in a concrete class, my Eclipse Indigo IDE makes it real easy to put in default implementations for all of the methods.  I can hover over the class name and then choose "Add unimplemented methods" and default implementations are all put in.  Not sure if you're using Eclipse or not but it has a lot of powerful features like that for automatic code insertion.

Comment: Yeah, I have been doing that. The two problems are that I then need to manually type `proxy.function_name()` and I need to rebuild the project every time the library is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Dynamic Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) may be able to do this. From the documentation:

> A dynamic proxy class is a class that implements a list of interfaces
>   specified at runtime such that a method invocation through one of the
>   interfaces on an instance of the class will be encoded and dispatched
>   to another object through a uniform interface. Thus, a dynamic proxy
>   class can be used to create a type-safe proxy object for a list of
>   interfaces without requiring pre-generation of the proxy class, such
>   as with compile-time tools.
>
> Method invocations on an instance of a dynamic proxy class are
>   dispatched to a single method in the instance's invocation handler,
>   and they are encoded with a java.lang.reflect.Method object
>   identifying the method that was invoked and an array of type Object
>   containing the arguments.

Comment: This sounds very promising! I'll try it out when I get home.